# Aggregate in mongodb with multiple conditions in match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following documents

```
{
        "_id" : "server1-1509181203-1",
        "V" : 0,
        "mp" : [
                "server1-1509181203-1"
        ],
        "cD" : ISODate("2017-10-28T09:00:03Z"),
        "wD" : ISODate("2017-10-28T09:00:03.838Z"),
        "asv" : 1,        
        "fromAddress" : "noreply@example.com",
        "fromUserId" : "noreply",
        "mailKind" : "custom",        
},
{
        "_id" : "server1-1509181203-1",
        "V" : 0,
        "mp" : [
                "server1-1509181203-1"
        ],
        "cD" : ISODate("2017-10-28T09:00:03Z"),
        "wD" : ISODate("2017-10-28T09:00:03.838Z"),
        "asv" : 1,        
        "fromAddress" : "noreply@example.com",
        "fromUserId" : "noreply",
        "mailKind" : "custom",        
},
{
        "_id" : "server2-1529181203-1",
        "V" : 0,
        "mp" : [
                "server2-1529181203-1"
        ],
        "cD" : ISODate("2017-10-27T09:00:03Z"),
        "wD" : ISODate("2017-10-27T09:00:03.838Z"),
        "asv" : 1,        
        "fromAddress" : "noreply@example.com",
        "fromUserId" : "noreply",
        "mailKind" : "standard",        
},
```

The goal is to get the count of e-mail sent per day grouped by mailKind

Expected results:-

```
{ "_id" : { "mailKind" : "custom", "DayOftheMonth" : 26 }, "cnt" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "mailKind" : "standard", "DayOftheMonth" : 27 }, "cnt" : 1 }
```

Query I have is :-

```
db.Collection.aggregate({ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-26T00:00:00.000Z")} } },{ $group : { _id : { mailKind : "$mailKind" , DayOftheMonth : { $dayOfMonth : "$cD"}}, cnt : {$sum : 1 } } })
```

Problem:-

The above query works for all mailKind but I want apply only for certain kind.
When I try following query I get an error

```
db.Example.aggregate({ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")} }, "mailKind" : [ "custom", "standard"] },{ $group : { _id : { mailKind : "$mailKind" , DayOftheMonth : { $dayOfMonth : "$cD"}}, cnt : {$sum : 1 } } })
```

Can't we use two or more condition in match expression ? Can someone please help.

Comment: Try `{ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")}, "mailKind" :{$in:[ "custom", "standard"] }}}`

Comment: thanks. Got the same error message "assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly o
ne field.",
        "code" : 16435
} : aggregate failed"

Comment: db.Example.aggregate({ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")} }, "mailKind" : {$in:[ "standard", "custom", "custom1" ] }},{ $group : { _id : { mailKind : "$mailKind" , DayOftheMonth : { $dayOfMonth : "$cD"}}, cnt : {$sum : 1 } } })

Comment: Try enclosing the aggregation pipeline in []. Try `db.Example.aggregate([{ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")} }, "mailKind" : {$in:[ "standard", "custom", "custom1" ] }},{ $group : { _id : { mailKind : "$mailKind" , DayOftheMonth : { $dayOfMonth : "$cD"}}, cnt : {$sum : 1 } } }])`

Comment: same error. Can we add any number of condition in $match? From what I tried it is complaining when I add more than one condition. If try them individually its working.

Comment: Sorry my original match was correct. You have a misplaced brace after ISODate. Try `db.Example.aggregate([{ $match : { "cD" : { $gte: ISODate("2018-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")}, "mailKind" : {$in:[ "standard", "custom", "custom1" ] } }},{ $group : { _id : { mailKind : "$mailKind" , DayOftheMonth : { $dayOfMonth : "$cD"}}, cnt : {$sum : 1 } } }])`